# Micronaut ExceptionHandler: create HttpResponse with status code and body

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

In my Micronaut application I have defined an `ExceptionHandler`, which should catch `WorkflowException` and return an `HttpResponse` with status code 412 and with `WorkflowExceptionVM` as body.

Here is my current implementation:

```
@Produces
@Singleton
@Requires(classes = [WorkflowException::class, ExceptionHandler::class])
class WorkflowExceptionHandler : ExceptionHandler<WorkflowException, HttpResponse<WorkflowExceptionVM>> {

    override fun handle(request: HttpRequest<Any>, exception: WorkflowException): HttpResponse<WorkflowExceptionVM> {
        return HttpResponse.status<WorkflowExceptionVM>(HttpStatus.PRECONDITION_FAILED)
                .body(WorkflowExceptionVM(exception.code))
    }
}
```

It produces a response with the correct code, but does not include the body.

Here is my test:

```
@Test
fun `Should handle WorkflowException`() {
    val request = POST(THE_URL, THE_BODY).basicAuth("user", "password")
    val exception = shouldThrow<HttpClientResponseException>
        {client.toBlocking().exchange(request, MyEntity::class.java) }

    exception.response.code() shouldBe 412 // This works
    exception.response.body() // ERROR: this is null
}
```

How to add the body to the response?

Answer (score 3):

To get the error body you need to use the 3 parameters `exchange` method in which the 3rd one is the error type: https://docs.micronaut.io/1.2.x/api/io/micronaut/http/client/DefaultHttpClient.html#exchange-io.micronaut.http.HttpRequest-io.micronaut.core.type.Argument-io.micronaut.core.type.Argument-

So, your code should be:

```
val exception = shouldThrow<HttpClientResponseException>
        {client.toBlocking().exchange(request, MyEntity::class.java, WorkflowExceptionVM::class.java) }
```

I'm not 100% sure if that will work in Kotlin or not because in Java you need to wrap the `bodyType` and the `errorType` inside an `Argument`. 
In case it doesn't work, please try with:

```
val exception = shouldThrow<HttpClientResponseException>
        {client.toBlocking().exchange(request, Argument.of(MyEntity::class.java), Argument.of(WorkflowExceptionVM::class.java)) }
```

UPDATE:
The extract the body from the exception use `exception.getResponse().getBody(WorkflowExceptionVM::class.java)`. This returns an `Optional` so you can check that the body present and the get it and check any property on `WorkflowExceptionVM`.

Comment: Thank you! You are right that the problem is in the test code (I checked with Postman that the error body is actually present as expected). Your first code sample does not compile. Adding only the expected body type without wrapping it into `Argument.of()` works fine, but if the error type is also present, both must be wrapped.

The second sample compiles, but the body is still null as before.

Comment: I've updated my answeser with how to extract to body. Again, please keep in mind that it may not compile directly in Kotlin, I'm just "translating" the equivalent Java code (actually Groovy because I use Spock for tests)